# Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 11 seconds

Tags: angular, protractor

I'm new to Protractor and am trying to write test cases for a very simple scenario: Going to a login page and submitting the form, redirecting to the dashboard page, and then clicking a search button on the dashboard. The logging in part is working fine:

pages/login.js:

```
'use strict';

var LoginPage = function () {
    this.email = element(by.css('#email'));
    this.password = element(by.css('#password'));
    this.submit = element(by.css('[type="submit"]'));

    expect(this.email.isPresent()).toBe(true, 'Email field not found');
    expect(this.password.isPresent()).toBe(true, 'Password field not found');
    expect(this.submit.isPresent()).toBe(true, 'Submit button not found');
};

module.exports = new LoginPage();
```

test-spec.js:

```
it('should log in', function () {
        console.log('Logging into Application.');
        browser.get('https://example.com/auth/login');

        var loginPage = require('./pages/login');
        loginPage.email.sendKeys('myemail@example.com');
        loginPage.password.sendKeys('mypassword');
        loginPage.submit.click();

        console.log('Waiting to be redirected to the dashboard page...');
        return browser.driver.wait(function () {
            return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function (url) {
                return /dashboard/.test(url);
            });
        }, 30000);
    });
```

However, when I then attempt to find the search button and click on it...

pages/dashboard.js:

```
'use strict';

    var DashboardPage = function () {
        var elementFromSecondPage = $('a[href*="/property/search"]');
        console.log('trying to wait for element to be visible: ' + elementFromSecondPage);
        browser.wait(protractor.until.elementIsVisible(elementFromSecondPage), 60000, 'Error: Element did not display within 1 minute');
        console.log('done waiting');

        console.log('trying to find this.search element');
        this.search = element(by.css('a[href*="/property/search"]'));
        console.log('this.search: ' + this.search);

        expect(this.search.isPresent()).toBe(true, 'Search button not found');
    };

    module.exports = new DashboardPage();
```

test-spec.js:

```
it('should go to search', function () {
        console.log('Going to the Search page.');
        var dashboardPage = require('./pages/dashboard');
        dashboardPage.search.click();
    });
```

When trying to find the search button, it errors:

Logging into Upstream.
Waiting to be redirected to the dashboard page...
Going to the Search page.
trying to wait for element to be visible: [object Object]
done waiting
trying to find this.search element 
this.search: [object Object]
Failures: 1) angularjs upstream add listing should go to search   Message:  Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 11 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an Angular application. Please see the FAQ for more details: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular While waiting for element with locator - Locator: By(css selector, a[href*="/property/search"])

Here is the html for the element that I'm searching for:

```
<a routerlinkactive="active" class="caret rpr-labeled-button rpr-labeled-button-search-alt active" href="/property/search">
...     
</a>
```

I've tried a number of different solutions to try and wait for the dashboard page and its DOM to load, but I still get this error no matter what. It's confusing because if you look at the output above, when I do a jQuery find it successfully loads the element so it's clearly there.

Answer (score 1):

The issue ended up being what @Gunderson suggested. Angular was making continuous (polling) networking calls, so Protractor never saw it as "done" loading. Hence, every find element call timed out no matter how long I waited.

As a hack, I used this command to disable the waiting:

```
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
```

This worked, however then what's the point of using Protractor over another testing framework, if it doesn't have special waiting for Angular apps? We then changed the web application that we're testing to disable the polling when running tests on it (via a querystring parameter on the login page), then everything started working beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

All `browser.wait()` does is schedule a command to wait for a condition. You indicated that your JQuery selector `$('a[href*="/property/search"]');` is working to get the element. **A possible workaround** is to create your own function that has it's own timeout and will use that selector to find the element and return a boolean true once element found or false on timeout.

```
function waitForElem(){
   //JQuery timeout logic here
   if(elementFound){ return true}
   else{//after some time interval
         return false;
   }
}
```

Then in your Protractor code still use `browser.wait()`

```
browser.wait(waitFormElem(), 60000, 'Error: Element did not display within 1 minute');
```

*I apologize for the pseudo code, but I really don't know JQuery and it appears you do so I figured you are informed enough to implement that logic*

Comment: I ended up doing a browser.sleep and waiting a long time (where the element is definitely loaded on the page), and yet the element(by.css) call still generates the error. I also tried simpler selectors on other elements and they all fail as well. So it's as if no elements can be found on the dashboard page after redirecting from login.

Comment: You said that page is a non-Angular page though right?

Comment: Sorry, I should've specified that. They're both angular pages.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I was thinking the page wasn't an Angular page. Probably sounds silly, but have you tried just adding an `id` to your element and using `elment(by.id('someId'))` ?

Comment: Angular pages can still have timeout issues due to outstanding $http or $timeout calls.  After you navigate, disable angular and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library: 
https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions 
There is several option for waiting element to be visible, to be clickable, to contain some text in it, check what suits you best. I usually wait element to be visible like this:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.css('a[href*="/property/search"]'))), 30000, "Element is not visible");
```